# Tag proposal: [cronbachs-alpha]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-proposal

[Cronbach's $\alpha$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cronbach's_alpha) is an estimate of the reliability of a psychometric test. It's admittedly rather field-specific, and I don't think many people outside of psychology or psychometrics have ever heard of it. Nevertheless, it and its properties seem to be squarely on topic as CV.

[And we have no less than *149 questions on it*.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=cronbach+is%3Aq) But no tag.

Skimming through the first couple of questions, it seems like few questions mention Cronbach's $\alpha$ but would not profit from the tag. (Little wonder, since it's a rather specific thing.) Thus, I propose that:

1. We create a tag [cronbachs-alpha](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cronbachs-alpha).
2. Some Higher Being (moderator? SE developer?) mass-retags-without-bumping all questions that contain "Cronbach's alpha", perhaps looking specifically at those questions that already have the five maximum tags.

I'll post a couple of possible actions. Please upvote whatever seems best to you.

Comment: As far as I know, there exists no way of mass-retagging-without-bumping that you envisage. The only existing type of mass-retagging-without-bumping is removing a tag; it's called tag burnination and can be done by SE admins (not by mods).

Comment: Creating the tag is pretty uncontroversial; I think there's clearly some point to having the tag. You can create it and the tag wiki (but the rest of your question about how to deal with the existing cases would remain after that creation). To my recollection, in the past the advice has been to add it to the few most important posts immediately, then a few at a time after that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Create the tag, don't mass-retag - retag slowly, one question at a time, not too many all at once, so we don't bump-flood the landing page.

Comment: +1. I have created several tags that I felt could be applied to many (dozens or even hundreds) of existing questions. What I did then was to look through these questions, find the most important ones (perhaps one or two dozens) and add the new tag to those.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe let's add `[cronbach-alpha]` (without **'s**) as a synonym..? I guess it will make searching easier since people may drop "s" in their queries. What do you think?

Comment: If you start typing cronba... in any tag window, [cronbachs-alpha] will pop up as a suggestion. So I am not sure I see a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Create the tag, mass-retag-without-bumping. (Assuming this is possible.)

Comment: This is not possible!

Answer (score -4):

Don't create the tag. Who cares about Cronbach's $\alpha$, anyways?

Comment: The people who ask the question, presumably.